# add diffrent images to a page

Tags: theme-development

I want to add diffrent images to a page,the_post_thumbnail_url() just show feature image but I don't want to dispaly feature image at all!
what should I do?
Is there another solution?

Comment: you don't want to use the page editor itself to put media straight in your page content? can you be more clear about what you want? like do you want users to upload images in a separate section when they're editing a post?

Comment: I want let admin to upload his project images as a post

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are editing a page/post, if yes, go to the right panel, under `Features Image`, remove it

Comment: and after remove it how can I put other images?

Comment: Hi @hadis you may added it from the same place you removed, you may add image from gallery or upload new image to it :D